# Changing syntax in a new Javascript framework

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework

Boredom got the best of me last month, and I've been working on a library for JavaScript ever since. I've read about 20-something tutorials, and plenty of documentation.

And now that I have a tiny, simple (but working) library, I want to change the syntax that is used when writing the code.

And I think I may have just found a way to do it. Or, more possibly, I may have just embarrassed myself with the following line, and question:

```
string     = new String('string');
```

That line up there; does it create a new `type` of type `string`, and call it `string`? Or does that line do something else, or is it basically the same as:

```
string string = "hey";
```

The reason I am asking is, I am interested in learning how to change things. I would like to be able to declare a new string like this, in my tiny js library:

```
txt someString = "hey";
```

... where `txt` is the data type 'string'.

And then use it like this:

```
if(someString == "hey") { return true; }
```

Comment: Neither `string string = "hey";` nor `txt someString = "hey";` can possibly be JavaScript syntax.  There's only one type of string primitive in JavaScript, and you can't make more.

Comment: Also here's a tip: stay away from w3schools, and in general don't trust much JavaScript information from before about 2010.

Comment: Yeah, no offense to anyone, but I've never trusted W3Schools all that much.

Comment: What you're trying to do seems (in my opinion) to be kinda pointless, there are various ways it 'could' be done (see @Bergi's answer) but first ask 'why' you would want to. Instead look at how jQuery, Dojo, Require, etc handle these types of things. There's no point reinventing the wheel (unless you have a *really* good reason to do so)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
txt someString = "hey";
```

You can not change Javascript's syntax. If you really want to do that, you'll have to write your own programming language. See [Learning to write a compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669/learning-to-write-a-compiler). If you want this programming language to be usable in a web browser, you will need to compile your language to Javascript. [CoffeeScript](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script) is one such language that does exactly this.

Answer (score 2):

`string = new String('string');` creates a new object (being an instanceof `String`) which has the internal value `"string"` (a string [primitive value]) and assigns it to a variable whose identifier is named "string". The second and third lines are invalid in JavaScript.

```
> var strObj = new String("string");
> var strVal = "string";
> typeof strObj
"object"
> typeof strVal
"string"
> strObj == strVal
true
> strObj === strVal
false
> strObj instanceof String
true
> strVal instanceof String
false
```

Usually, you never ever need `String` instances. If you access methods of string values in JS, they are automatically coerced to objects.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Is it possible to change the way we declare a String in a js library without changing the underlying data type? Or am I using my imagination too much?

Comment: You don't *declare* strings in JavaScript, which is a loose-typed language. What exactly do you mean by "*underlying data type*"? Strings are strings, there is only one type for textual data. Those objects are only needed for String methods by prototypical inheritance.

Comment: What I mean is, instead of writing `string msg = "hi";` I want to `write txt msg = "hi";`

Comment: What is `txt`? There is only one string type in JS, and variables (like `msg`) have no type.